# How to enable hash table index in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, indexing, hashtable, b-tree

On MySQL 5.7, I whenever I create an index, despite specifying its type (BTREE or HASH), the index created is always BTREE. Does anyone know how to enable HASH for indexing? I plan to use it on low cardinality columns.

Comment: Which engine do you use (InnoDB, MyISAM, Memory ...) ?

Comment: InnoDB --------

Comment: Hash, if it existed, would be only marginally better than BTree for point queries, and would be useless for "range" queries.  So, they did not bother to include it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

InnoDb and MyIsam don't support Hash index ( https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html )

[image]

But you can use adaptive hash index ( 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-adaptive-hash.html )